# node "require" hoisted to top outside of script -- loses access to variables from outer function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm requiring different files at the top of my main script in node. All my require statements are hoisted to the top. This creates a problem because when the methods within those imported scripts are invoked they do not have access to the function within which they are invoked (Because they are inevitably defined outside those functions due to the hoisting issue). Therefore, I must always pass variables in an options object. Has anyone experiences a similar issue? Is there some sort of standard workaround that people use? Thanks!

```js
function outer(){
  //let's pretend we're in a node environment
  //this required script will get hoisted to the very top and therefore lose access to the "something" variable!
  var common = require('../globals/common.js');
  var something = "something";
  

   common.printsomething();//will return "something is not defined"

};

outer();
```

Comment: It's not hoisting, it's a misunderstanding of how modules work. They don't have access to the scope of the caller.

Comment: Supposing that `common.printsomething()` was supposed to reach `something`, then no, there is no way to do that. But I have the feeling I don t understand what you are asking.

Comment: @robertklep: I can't seem to find a good resource that explains how the modules work. Do you have a link perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: Modules are like sealed little black boxes that you ship out to other functions. The code inside the box can't see outside of itself, but the calling code can put stuff into the box and get stuff out. Does this make a little sense?

Answer (score 1):

Hm.

I would assume that it'd ultimately be better to pass 'something' to the printsomething method, like so.

`common.printfoo('bar'); //returns 'bar'`

Typically, what you're doing there isn't how modules in node works. Yes, breaking up a large program into separate files is an excellent way to organize a project, but I'm afraid that I have to say you're doing it wrong here. In the context of 'outer', you could do:

```
/*script.js*/
var common = require('../globals/common.js');

function outer(str){
     common.printsomething(str);//will return "something"
};
var something = 'something';
outer(something);

/*common.js*/
function printthing(str){
   console.log(str);
}
module.exports = {
   printsomething: function(str){
       printthing(str)
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that I shouldn't be using "require" to break up my code into separate files? Is that bad practice?

Comment: No, no. It's definitely good practice to use different js files as an organizer. See my example for a good way to actually do that, however.

Comment: @orlandomarinella: You should make more clear the separation of the files, it may help mags understand better.

Comment: No problem, hold on.

Comment: @orlandomarinella: That will work but I don't want to have to pass anything to "common.printsomething()". The reason is that there are a bunch of variables I need that method to access and I don't want to keep passing them all as a huge options object. I was hoping that common.printsomething would just magically have access to those variables because it's invoked in that context, but the location of the definition is what counts and in this case the method is defined at the very top (whether you put it there or it gets hoisted there)

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to. It's the way JavaScript (and most programming languages, for that matter) work. What other languages are you fluent in?

Comment: I think I am looking for a solution that does not exist! I just had this feeling the whole time that I was somehow missing some magic solution because it felt weird to be passing so many variables via an options object. However, I will deal with it. thanks!

Comment: What you could do is set thoses environment variables inside the module instead of passing them left and right thought.

Comment: True. Environment variables tend to be a pain, though.

Comment: @mags: You can look at my edit for a example of environment variables, but you should try and practice with module before using it. I just hope you have a better understanding of modules.

Answer (score 1):

module.js:

```
module.exports.print = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

module.exports.add = function (a, b, callback) {
    callback(a + b);
}
```

main.js

```
var mymodule = require('module');

module.print('Some data'); //Will print "Some data" in the console
module.add(25, 12, function (result) {
    console.log(result);   //Will print 37
});
```

As you can see, in main.js, I do not need to know the content of module.js to wrk. that is the goal of modules: put the hard logic somewhere else, to build better code. Modules like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#Documentation) or [fs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) are huge and complex, but I just have to import them to work with it, and don't need to know how it does it.

While building your own module, think of it as a new library of tools, so that you can reuse it in another project without the need to set specific variables to use them. Imagine the chaos it would be if two module were able to get the content of your var `something` for unrelated goal!

Modules are self contained, to be reusable. A "de hoisting" of thoses would reduce their efficacity.

EDIT:

If you have a lot of environment variable, you can try a pattern where you set them once inside the module, but you have to make sure to provide a way to interact with them.

module:

```
var data = {};

function set(key, value) {
    data[key] = value;
}

function get(key) {
    return data[key];
}

function print(key) {
    console.log(data[key]);
}

function add(keyA, keyB) {
    return data[keyA] + data[keyB];
}

module.exports = {
    set: set,
    get: get,
    print: print,
    add: add
};
```

main.js

```
var mymod = require('mymod');

mymod.set('data', 'something');
mymod.set('a', 25);
mymod.set('b', 12);

mymod.print('data'); //Print "something"
var c = mymod.add('a', 'b');
console.log(c); //Print 32
```